# IntelliJ IDEA Can't create GUI Form

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, intellij-idea

Supposedly creating a new GUI form should be a simple matter of right-clicking your project, package or src folder and go New > GUI Form. The problem is I don't have that option. I've created a Java project and it compiles and runs fine.

But the only options I get under New are Java Class, File, Package, HTML File, and JavaScript File.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem. And the first answer "check that UI Designer is enabled" didn't help -- it's enabled.  I'm still looking for the single doc that completely specifies the steps needed to start a GUI module.

Comment: same here. plugin is enabled, but there is no new gui form menu

Answer (score 18):

Really old question, but if I got here someone else may as well...

So, step by step:

1. Make sure that the "UI designer" is enabled:

   > File -> Settings -> Plugins -> UI Designer (checked)
2. The parent (root) folder must be market as "source root"

   > Right click on the folder -> Mark Directory as -> Source root
3. Create a package from the "src" folder:

   > Right click on the "src" folder -> New -> Package
4. Create the new form:

   > Right click on the package -> new GUI Form

PS. I'm not sure, but I reckon it's possible to skip the package step...

Comment: Good info thanks, any idea what is the reason why we need to mark the parent (root) folder as source root?

Comment: I guess it's probably something to do with how IntelliJ organizes itself; not sure though

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful, was missing the marking directory step

Answer (score 16):

Double check that you have **UI Designer** enabled in `Settings` | `Plugins`.

Answer (score 6):

You need the create a package, and after you can create GUI forms.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a package, *and have open a class file within the package*, and *THEN* you can create GUI forms.  The options in the File -> New menu change depending on what kind of file you are currently editing.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but it still deserves a straight answer.  I had to right click the package itself inside the project directories.  You cannot use the "file > new" option.  So once you create your package, right click the directory you want the files created in, go to new > GUI Form

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version it's like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the only change I needed to do was to use `one word` in the input fields for the New GUI Form dialog. When I tried clicking the OK button no error message or warnings were displayed, just nothing happened. Probably a pretty obvious thing, but worth sharing in case anyone else runs into it.