# can't find 'GUI Designer' in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Trying to use intellij GUI Designer but couldn't find File | Settings | Editor | GUI Designer, saw here: [IntelliJ IDEA Can't create GUI Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118589/intellij-idea-cant-create-gui-form) to check if

> UI Designer plugin

is enabled, but couldn't find him in the list, nor download it from the repository.

my intellij version is:
2016.3.4

Comment: You should create a form first, [refer to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/designing-gui-major-steps.html).

Comment: I open an existing project that already has many forms

Comment: Opening a `.form` file from the source root will open gui designer.